# Postgresql data not updated with query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to change one column's value in every row to a exact value with `sql` query like this:

```sql
 UPDATE cs_houmon_ SET time_stamp='1999-01-10 11:11:11.11111';
```

Output is

```
UPDATE 281046
```

But when I select all data a take a look, the value doesn't change. Am I forgetting some kind of `commit` or something?

When I try

```sql
UPDATE cs_houmon_ SET time_stamp='1999-01-10 11:11:11.111111'; COMMIT;
```

output is

```sql
UPDATE 281046
WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress
COMMIT
```

Column was added to table like this

```sql
alter table cs_houmon_ add column time_stamp timestamp default current_timestamp;
```

After that I changed it to

```sql
ALTER TABLE ONLY cs_houmon_ ALTER COLUMN time_stamp SET DEFAULT '1999-01-10 11:11:11.111111';
```

And here is a trigger I was using in `current_timestamp` previously

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_modified_column() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.time_stamp = now();
    RETURN NEW; 
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';


CREATE TRIGGER update_customer_modtime BEFORE UPDATE ON cs_houmon_ FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE  update_modified_column();
```

Comment: "Am I forgetting some kind of `commit` or something?" -- Possible. Did you try a `COMMIT`?

Comment: output is `UPDATE 281046 \n
 WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress \n 
 COMMIT`

Comment: OK, then provide more details. [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables and/or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: I updated it for that column

Comment: So the trigger is overwriting your literal value.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks! Also could you please provide a way to disable trigger?

Comment: `DROP TRIGGER update_customer_modtime`?

Comment: getting: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"

Comment: got it this way: `DROP TRIGGER update_customer_modtime on cs_houmon_;`